# How to store values of a repeating XML structure

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to parse an XML file with repeating structure blocks, but the element values in the structure blocks are different.I need to store all the values from repeating structure blocks. i am not able to figure out an efficient way to do it.

I was able to store the Masterdata section. Also, i tried to store the alias section for different blocks in a List, but its messy. i am not able to figure out the value comes from which section.

```
public class PRecord : ConnectorDoc
    {
        public string creationDate { get; internal set; }

        public string system { get; internal set; }

        public string partReference { get; internal set; }

        public string partNumber { get; internal set; }

        public string partNumber_confidence { get; internal set; }

        public string partType { get; internal set; }

        public string description { get; internal set; }

        public string revision { get; internal set; }

        public string status { get; internal set; }

        public string part_type { get; internal set; }

        public string part_source { get; internal set; }

        public string category { get; internal set; }

        public string source { get; internal set; }

        public string productLifeCycle { get; internal set; }

        public List<ARecord> aliases { get; internal set; }


       }

 public class ARecord : ConnectorDoc
    {

        public string a_partNumber { get; set; }

        public string a_ManufName { get; set; }

        public string a_DnBCode { get; set; }

        public string a_category { get; set; }

    }

private IEnumerable<PRecord> parse_file(string xml_file)
        {
            XNamespace ns = "";



            XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml_file);

            IEnumerable<PRecord> records = from pr in xmlDoc.Descendants("result")

                                           select new PRecord
                                           {

                                               Id = Sys.NewId(),

                                               Version = Sys.GetVersionDate(),

                                               SourceStr1 = pr.Descendants("MasterData").ElementAt(0).Element("MasterSystem") == null ? "" : pr.Descendants("MasterData").ElementAt(0).Element("MasterSystem").Value,

                                               SourceStr2 = pr.Descendants("MasterData").ElementAt(0).Element("MasterPartType") == null ? "" : pr.Descendants("MasterData").ElementAt(0).Element("MasterPartType").Value,

                                               SourceStr3 = pr.Descendants("MasterData").ElementAt(0).Element("PartNumber") == null ? "" : pr.Descendants("MasterData").ElementAt(0).Element("PartNumber").Value,

                                               SourceStr4 = pr.Descendants("MasterData").ElementAt(0).Element("Revision") == null ? "" : pr.Descendants("MasterData").ElementAt(0).Element("Revision").Value,

                                               SourceStr5 = pr.Descendants("MasterData").ElementAt(0).Element("Description") == null ? "" : pr.Descendants("MasterData").ElementAt(0).Element("Description").Value,

                                               SourceStr6 = pr.Descendants("MasterData").ElementAt(0).Element("UoM") == null ? "" : pr.Descendants("MasterData").ElementAt(0).Element("UNSPSC").Value,





                                               source = pr.Element("source") == null ? "" : pr.Element("source").Value,

                                               category = pr.Element("category") == null ? "" : pr.Element("category").Value,

                                               productLifeCycle = pr.Element("productLifeCycle") == null ? "" : pr.Element("productLifeCycle").Value,

                                               aliases = (from alias in pr.Descendants("alias")

                                                          select new ARecord

                                                          {

                                                              a_partNumber = alias.Element("partNumber") == null ? "" : alias.Element("partNumber").Value,

                                                              a_ManufName = alias.Element("ManufName") == null ? "" : alias.Element("ManufName").Value,

                                                              a_DnBCode = alias.Element("DnBCode") == null ? "" : alias.Element("DnBCode").Value,

                                                              a_category = alias.Element("category") == null ? "" : alias.Element("category").Value,



                                                          }).ToList(),

                                           };

            return records;

        }
```

sample XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <MasterData>
      <MasterSystem>ABC</MasterSystem>
      <MasterPartType>SP</MasterPartType>
      <MasterCode />
      <PartNumber>CV123</PartNumber>
      <Revision>A</Revision>
      <Description>Test1</Description>
      <UoM>EA</UoM>
      <UNSPSC>3212</UNSPSC>
   </MasterData>
   <AliasSystem>
      <envelope xmlns="">
         <headers>
            <creationDate xmlns="">2019-04-08</creationDate>
         </headers>
         <triples />
         <instance>
            <partReference xmlns="">
               <system>Sys1</system>
               <partNumber confidence="100">DTR342</partNumber>
               <partType>SP</partType>
               <description>Test2</description>
               <status>Current</status>
               <revision>-</revision>
               <UNSPSC />
               <UoM>EA</UoM>
               <type>A_SP</type>
               <source>S1</source>
               <category>pref</category>
               <productLifeCycle>False</productLifeCycle>
               <aliasList>
                  <alias valid="true" confidence="100" reference="MR">
                     <partNumber>R413I2100#00M</partNumber>
                     <ManufName>KM</ManufName>
                     <DnBCode>78842</DnBCode>
                     <category>MR</category>
                  </alias>
                  <alias valid="true" confidence="100" reference="Manu">
                     <partNumber>PME271</partNumber>
                     <ManufName>KE</ManufName>
                     <DnBCode>788421</DnBCode>
                     <category>MR</category>
                  </alias>
               </aliasList>
            </partReference>
         </instance>
         <attachments />
      </envelope>
   </AliasSystem>
   <MasterSystem>
      <envelope xmlns="">
         <headers>
            <creationDate xmlns="">2019-04-10</creationDate>
         </headers>
         <triples />
         <instance>
            <partReference xmlns="">
               <system>Sys2</system>
               <partNumber confidence="100">DTR123</partNumber>
               <partType>SP</partType>
               <UoM>EA</UoM>
               <description>test3</description>
               <status>CURRENT</status>
               <productLifeCycle />
               <revision>A</revision>
               <TISIndex />
               <manager>CMF</manager>
               <UNSPSC>3212</UNSPSC>
               <category>Pref</category>
               <source>S2</source>
               <aliasList>
                  <alias valid="true" confidence="100" reference="Manu">
                     <partNumber>R413I2</partNumber>
                     <DnBCode />
                     <name>KE</name>
                     <status>S : Pr</status>
                     <category>MR</category>
                  </alias>
                  <alias valid="true" confidence="100" reference="Manu">
                     <partNumber>PME271Y510MR30</partNumber>
                     <DnBCode />
                     <name>KEMET</name>
                     <status>S : Product maturity</status>
                     <category>ManufacturerRef</category>
                  </alias>
                  <alias valid="true" confidence="100" reference="Legacy">
                     <partNumber>--</partNumber>
                     <owner>PLM</owner>
                     <category>LegacyPartRef</category>
                  </alias>

               </aliasList>
            </partReference>
         </instance>
         <attachments />
      </envelope>
   </MasterSystem>
   <AliasSystem>
      <envelope xmlns="">
         <headers>
            <creationDate xmlns="">2019-04-10</creationDate>
         </headers>
         <triples />
         <instance>
            <partReference xmlns="">
               <system>ERP</system>
               <partNumber confidence="100">DTR02</partNumber>
               <partType />
               <UoM>EA</UoM>
               <mandantStatus>ZB</mandantStatus>
               <description />
               <status>J5PARTSTATUS2</status>
               <productLifeCycle />
               <category>pR</category>
               <source>S3</source>
               <aliasList />
            </partReference>
         </instance>
         <attachments />
      </envelope>
   </AliasSystem>
</result>
```

There is one MasterSystem section and there are multiple AliasSystem sections in the XML file. I want to store the 'creationdate', 'partreference'(all chlidren) and the aliaslist from each section(MasterSystem and AliasSystem sections). But i am trying to store the data in a way to identify the section its parsed from(defining criteria system or source element).

Comment: Your XML doesn't seem to be a valid XML.

Comment: Do you have a definition for ARecord?

Comment: this is the one. ` public class ARecord : ConnectorDoc
    {

        public string a_partNumber { get; set; }

        public string a_ManufName { get; set; }

        public string a_DnBCode { get; set; }

        public string a_category { get; set; }

    }`

Comment: And is ConnectorDoc important for this discussion? If so, do you have a definition of that as well?

Comment: connectorDoc is not required for this discussion. its just simple inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following using XMl Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication108
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement result = doc.Root;

            List<PRecord> records = new List<PRecord>();

            List<XElement> systems = result.Elements("MasterSystem").ToList();
            systems.AddRange(result.Elements("AliasSystem"));

            foreach (XElement system in systems)
            {
                PRecord newRecord = new PRecord();
                records.Add(newRecord);

                newRecord.systemType = system.Name.LocalName;

                newRecord.creationDate = (DateTime)system.Descendants("creationDate").FirstOrDefault();

                XElement partReference = system.Descendants("partReference").FirstOrDefault();

                XElement xPartNumber = partReference.Element("partNumber");
                newRecord.partNumber = (string)xPartNumber;
                newRecord.partNumber_confidence = (int)xPartNumber.Attribute("confidence");

                newRecord.partType = (string)partReference.Element("partType");
                newRecord.description = (string)partReference.Element("description");
                newRecord.revision = (string)partReference.Element("revision");
                newRecord.status = (string)partReference.Element("status");
                newRecord.category = (string)partReference.Element("category");
                newRecord.source = (string)partReference.Element("source");
                newRecord.productLifeCycle = (string)partReference.Element("productLifeCycle");

                List<XElement> aliases = partReference.Descendants("alias").ToList();

                foreach (XElement alias in aliases)
                {
                    if (newRecord.aliases == null) newRecord.aliases = new List<ARecord>();

                    ARecord newARecord = new ARecord();
                    newRecord.aliases.Add(newARecord);

                    newARecord.a_partNumber = (string)alias.Element("partNumber");
                    newARecord.a_DnBCode = (string)alias.Element("DnBCode");
                    newARecord.a_ManufName = (string)alias.Element("name");
                    newARecord.a_category = (string)alias.Element("status");
                    newARecord.a_status = (string)alias.Element("category");
                }
            }



        }

    }


    public class PRecord
    {
        public string systemType { get; internal set; }
        public DateTime creationDate { get; internal set; }

        public string system { get; internal set; }
        public string partNumber { get; internal set; }
        public int partNumber_confidence { get; internal set; }
        public string partType { get; internal set; }
        public string description { get; internal set; }
        public string revision { get; internal set; }
        public string status { get; internal set; }
        public string part_source { get; internal set; }
        public string category { get; internal set; }
        public string source { get; internal set; }
        public string productLifeCycle { get; internal set; }

        public List<ARecord> aliases { get; internal set; }


    }

    public class ARecord
    {
        public string a_partNumber { get; set; }
        public string a_ManufName { get; set; }
        public string a_DnBCode { get; set; }
        public string a_category { get; set; }
        public string a_status { get; set; }
    }


}
```